# Kineticjs can't find my object after rotation change with drag

Tags: html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have made a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mFxhS/1/ but strangely doesn't work well but still you can see the whole code.

But I have did some console.log's and he does know the identifiers but still with the `layer.get('#group'+i)[0]` he can't finds them.

With the following on line 126:

```
console.log(layer.getChildren());
console.log(i);
console.log(this.getId());
console.log(stage.get('#group'+i)[0].getId());
```

you normally get:

```
[Kinetic.Rect, Kinetic.Rect, Kinetic.Group]
0 
group0 
group0
```

but when I rotate the object then I get:

```
[Kinetic.Rect, Kinetic.Rect, Kinetic.Group]
0 
group0 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getId' of undefined
```

How can this happen? And if I look into the first console line there you have still the same objects with the same _ID en and the same attribute ID.

Sorry for the broken jsFiddle, I don't understand why it isn't working.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to KineticJS 4.4

I confirm your rect's get lost sometimes under 4.0 and 4.3--In fact, I can't even rotate in your Fiddle (the rect's move instead of rotate).

When I run your same code in version 4.4:  no lost rectangles and rotation works fine.

Just a side issue: you might want to reposition your rotation handles closer to the rect after rotation. Currently, the rotation handles can stay far away from the rect after rotation.

Comment: Wow thanks, it's working perfectly now on my localhost. I was getting worried about my programming knowledge. You am right about the side issue. Now I can move on, thanks.